# Where does the java 7 gervill soundbank live on Windows

Tags: java, windows, gervill

The java 7 gervill soundbank lives in directory .gervill on MacOSx. What is the corresponding location on Windows? Also, does anyone know why the default sounds are different on these two platforms

Comment: Seems like a google search or reading the docs should answer this for you.

Comment: Just give it a few weeks and this question will become the #1 result on Google ;-)

Comment: From the gmreadme.txt file found in the same directory:  "The GM.DLS file contains the Roland SoundCanvas Sound Set which is 
protected under the following copyright: 
Roland GS Sound Set/Microsoft (P) 1996 Roland Corporation U.S.  
The Roland SoundCanvas Sound Set is licensed under Microsoft's 
End User License Agreement for use with Microsoft operating 
system products only."  So it seems likely there are some licensing considerations in regard to why different sound fonts for each platform.

Answer (score 2):

Windows includes a "gm.dls" soundbank which is used if found. 
On MacOS and on other platforms a generated soundbank is used instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. The file is there. I will see if I can change it now.

Comment: Exactly where is the gm.dls file?